# Hard link duplicate files based on just size

Tags: ubuntu, deduplication

I'm currently running `rdfind` on a directory containing more than 4TB of files. Since the checksum part takes an inordinate amount of time I'm looking for alternatives. I know fairly certain that there aren't any size collisions based on `find /mnt/local/ -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort --numeric`. Is there a tool or script that can hard link any duplicate files based on just size or maybe the hash of the first couple thousand of bytes?

Comment: Just checked and `fdupes` can't disable the checksum check either (and you are correct, checksumming could be done in blocks of whatever to enable fail-fast, that would actually be a good feature request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`jdupes`](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) can be configured to only checksum the first block of data in each file, using the `-T` option; thus in your case,

```
jdupes -T -T -r -L /mnt/local
```

would hard-link all duplicates found under `/mnt/local`, based only on their size and the hashes of the first block.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!